Is there a reliable Google Apps Scripts function/algo that is able to tranfer embedded images from Sheets to Docs?
I've been working with a function within Google Apps Scripts trying to transfer an image and data from a Sheet (both of which come from a server), and to then transfer the formatted data and image to a Google Doc. Right now, I've got my data formatted and working well, but after looking into functions within Google Apps Scripts, I'm not totally sure if it's possible.
Disclaimer: I have seen the 2020 post regarding something similar to this using OverGridImage, but was hoping if there was a fix a couple years later!!
What I thought I could do was
function sendToCell() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const images = sheet.getImages(); 
  const doc = DocumentApp.create("Cell Images");
  const body = doc.getBody();
  
  if (images.length === 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("cell images not found");
    return;
  }

  images.forEach(image => {
    const blob = image.getBlob();
    const position = image.getAnchorCell().getA1Notation(); 
    
    body.appendParagraph(`Image from cell: ${position}`);
    body.appendImage(blob);
  });
  }

Which did not work as I thought, is this possible with Apps Scripts?

Modification points:

Class OverGridImage has no method of getBlob. Ref By this, I guess that an error occurs at const blob = image.getBlob();.
In the current stage, unfortunately, the blob cannot be directly retrieved from the over grid image. This has already been reported at the Google issue tracker. Ref So, in order to achieve thid, I created DocsServiceApp as a Google Apps Script library. Ref This library retrieves the images as blobs by parsing Spreadsheet as XLSX.

When this library is used in your script, it becomes as follows.
Install library
You can see how to install DocsServiceApp at here.
Enable Drive API
Please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.
Modified script
function sendToCell() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const images = DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(ss.getId()).getSheetByName(sheet.getSheetName()).getImages();
  if (images.length === 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("cell images not found");
    return;
  }
  const doc = DocumentApp.create("Cell Images");
  const body = doc.getBody();
  images.forEach(({ range, image }) => {
    if (!image.innerCell) {
      const blob = image.blob;
      const position = range.a1Notation;
      body.appendParagraph(`Image from cell: ${position}`);
      body.appendImage(blob);
    }
  });
}

When this script is run, the images over the cells are retrieved by DocsServiceApp and the retrieved images are put into the created Google Document.
Note:

From your showing script, this modified script retrieves only the images over the cells. If you want to include the images both in the cells and over the cells, please remove if (!image.innerCell) { and }.

Reference:

DocsServiceApp (Author: me)

